Subdivision modifier doesn't apply with face creation
I joined to separate object and when I want to connect them and create a face (with F), the subdivision modifier doesn't apply correctly. It behaves like if the mean crease was set to 1 on the edge but it's at 0...
Any idea why ?


hello, maybe flipped faces? Select all and press Shift N. Or check if you have inner faces? Or please share your file...

can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Shift + N did the trick ! What's this sorcery ??

hehe Hi, 16ar .. if the magician has done it for you in the commentary without needing a formal answer.. would it be OK  to close this out as a simple slip-up? Flipped normals / internal faces have been covered already on this stack, every now and then.

You have flipped faces, select all in Edit mode and press ShiftN to recalculate the normals.
